# How do I know which contract failed with Python's contract.py?

Tags: python, design-by-contract

I'm playing with [contract.py](http://www.wayforward.net/pycontract/), Terrence Way's reference implementation of design-by-contract for Python. The implementation throws an exception when a contract (precondition/postcondition/invariant) is violated, but it doesn't provide you a quick way of identifying which specific contract has failed if there are multiple ones associated with a method.

For example, if I take the [circbuf.py](http://www.wayforward.net/pycontract/examples/circbuf.py) example, and violate the precondition by passing in a negative argument, like so:

```
circbuf(-5)
```

Then I get a traceback that looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "circbuf.py", line 115, in <module>
    circbuf(-5)
  File "<string>", line 3, in __assert_circbuf___init___chk
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/contract.py", line 1204, in call_constructor_all
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/contract.py", line 1293, in _method_call_all
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/contract.py", line 1332, in _call_all
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/contract.py", line 1371, in _check_preconditions
contract.PreconditionViolationError: ('__main__.circbuf.__init__', 4)
```

My hunch is that the second argument in the PreconditionViolationError (4) refers to the line number in the circbuf.**init** docstring that contains the assertion:

```
def __init__(self, leng):
    """Construct an empty circular buffer.

    pre::
        leng > 0
    post[self]::
        self.is_empty() and len(self.buf) == leng
    """
```

However, it's a pain to have to open the file and count the docstring line numbers. Does anybody have a quicker solution for identifying which contract has failed?

(Note that in this example, there's a single precondition, so it's obvious, but multiple preconditions are possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but I may as well answer it. I added some output, you'll see it at the comment # jlr001. Add the line below to your contract.py and when it raises an exception it will show the doc line number and the statement that triggered it. Nothing more than that, but it will at least stop you from needing to guess which condition triggered it.

```
def _define_checker(name, args, contract, path):
    """Define a function that does contract assertion checking.

    args is a string argument declaration (ex: 'a, b, c = 1, *va, **ka')
    contract is an element of the contracts list returned by parse_docstring
    module is the containing module (not parent class)

    Returns the newly-defined function.

    pre::
        isstring(name)
        isstring(args)
        contract[0] in _CONTRACTS
        len(contract[2]) > 0
    post::
        isinstance(__return__, FunctionType)
        __return__.__name__ == name
    """
    output = StringIO()
    output.write('def %s(%s):\n' % (name, args))
    # ttw001... raise new exception classes
    ex = _EXCEPTIONS.get(contract[0], 'ContractViolationError')
    output.write('\tfrom %s import forall, exists, implies, %s\n' % \
                (MODULE, ex))
    loc = '.'.join([x.__name__ for x in path])
    for c in contract[2]:
        output.write('\tif not (')
        output.write(c[0])
        # jlr001: adding conidition statement to output message, easier debugging
        output.write('): raise %s("%s", %u, "%s")\n' % (ex, loc, c[1], c[0]))
    # ...ttw001

    # ttw016: return True for superclasses to use in preconditions
    output.write('\treturn True')
    # ...ttw016

    return _define(name, output.getvalue(), path[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying his code, I don't think you can, but since this is python...

If you look for where he raises the exception to the user, it I think is possible to push the info you're looking for into it... I wouldn't expect you to be able to get the trace-back to be any better though because the code is actually contained in a comment block and then processed.

The code is pretty complicated, but this might be a block to look at - maybe if you dump out some of the args you can figure out whats going on...

```
def _check_preconditions(a, func, va, ka):
    # ttw006: correctly weaken pre-conditions...
    # ab002: Avoid generating AttributeError exceptions...
    if hasattr(func, '__assert_pre'):
        try:
            func.__assert_pre(*va, **ka)
        except PreconditionViolationError, args:
            # if the pre-conditions fail, *all* super-preconditions
            # must fail too, otherwise
            for f in a:
                if f is not func and hasattr(f, '__assert_pre'):
                    f.__assert_pre(*va, **ka)
                    raise InvalidPreconditionError(args)
            # rr001: raise original PreconditionViolationError, not
            # inner AttributeError...
            # raise
            raise args
            # ...rr001
    # ...ab002
    # ...ttw006
```